# React Typescript: Line 0: Parsing error: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, react-scripts, react-typescript

Today suddenly I started to get build errors on a project built with Typescript. In a file that (or anything it references) hasn't been changed in weeks, I started to get:

```
./path/to/my/file.ts
  Line 0:  Parsing error: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

This error first appeared on our CI, could be replicated by manually building on the server, and I could finally reproduce on my own computer (which was running perfectly) after updating all packages. Now, even if I pull the old (building) commit of my project, I can't build it. I've got `yarn.lock` commited to my repo, but even with the old `package.json` and `yarn.lock` (I delete `node_modules` and do `yarn`), I can't build.

This error literally started out of blue today.

What could be the reason?

---

My (possibly relevant) versions:

```
yarn 1.22.4,
node v13.11.0,
typescript 3.7.5
react 16.12
react-scripts 3.4.0
macOS 10.15 Catalina
```

Comment: I have the same issue, have you found what causes the error?

Comment: @Kenjoe the problem went away by itself now. Probably some misconfiguration of peer dependencies of dependencies.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The problem apparently was caused by a misconfiguration of some (peer?) dependencies of a dependency, `react-scripts` with the TypeScript template. It went away. Make sure you update your dependencies, purge `node_modules`, even purge `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock`, and try a fresh build again now.

Comment: Weird, upgraded to `3.8.X` to no avail, purged `node_modules` installed again and good to go

Comment: Updating TS to 3.8.x fixed my eslint issues, but I kept failing the build until I purged node_modules and my *-lock.json files. I also closed and reopened my IDE just to be sure, and now things are working.

Comment: In August 2020, I fixed this by rolling back Typescript to `^3.9.5` after an automatic dependabot upgrade to `^4.0.2`. YMMV

Comment: If you are experiencing this issue after upgrading to TS 4.0, it is because create-react-app does not yet support TS 4.0 (or more accurately, it's dependencies don't).  https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9515 You can fix by downgrading TS, using a pre-release build of CRA 4.0, or force-pinning your ts-eslint an and parser dependencies per https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9515

Answer (score 8):

I case of an app generated by

`npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript`

More precisely, `create-react-app@3.4.1`

The issue was solved by running the following command:

`rm yarn-lock && rm -rf node_modules && npm i`

After which you may run:

either `yarn start` or `npm start`

Comment: Thanks for the call out for `cretae-react-app`. Following this solved my problem.

Comment: Although, I managed to get the app to compile with `yarn` as well after a couple of attempts at  removing `yarn.lock` and running `yarn`

Comment: Did it for me! Just removed the `node_modules` and then `yarn`, and that was it.

Answer (score 4):

Just update typescript version to 3.8.x : [Link](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/1761)

Comment: Nope, didn't solve mine. Updated to even 3.9 nightly but still the same.

Comment: On 4.0, still experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I just had to add an extra newline at the end of the ts file.

```
export * from './result';
export * from './request';
//new line here
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, **the culprit was asset imports of non-existing files**, e.g.:

```js
import { ReactComponent as SomeIcon } from '../assets/img/some-icon.svg';
```

The answers above helped me find the culprit. **I ran** `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm i && npm start`, **which caused the real errors to be shown** (instead of the unhelpful cryptic *"Line 0: Parsing error: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"*)

**Once I added the missing files, the errors went away.**

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs because your typescript is not compatible with your typescript-eslint plugins.

You can fix it by upgrading these two dependencies to the latest version.

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.6.0",
  "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.6.0",
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Updating react-scripts worked for me. `react-scripts 3.4.0` probably does not support `typescript 3.7.5`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was because I had TS code under `.\src` which was referencing TS code under `.\tools` but I only had `src` in the `include` in my `tsconfig.json`, adding `tools` fixed the issue