# React build failed: cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-app-rewired

I'm using create-react-app template with typescript. On my local pc, run build successfully, but when run in CI server, build failed.

- build error

> ./src/store/redux/info/index.ts Syntax error: Cannot read property
>   'name' of undefined (0:undefined)

But there is no 'name' property in file

**info/index.ts**

```
export { default } from "./reducer";
export * from "./actions";
export * from "./types";
```

```
 "react": "16.12.0",
 "react-app-rewired": "2.1.5",
 "antd": "3.26.5",
 "antd-theme-webpack-plugin": "1.3.0",
 "typescript": "3.7.4",
```

```
    "build": "react-app-rewired --max-old-space-size=8192 build",
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Typescript: Line 0: Parsing error: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60729199/react-typescript-line-0-parsing-error-cannot-read-property-name-of-undefine)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with 'typescript-eslint'.

It could be resolved by updating Typescript version to **3.8.x** - as pointed out by user **Phoebus** at an other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60734819/5758225

Github issue (and PR link in comments): https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/1746

Answer (score 2):

Update your typescript version to @latest. 3.8.3 as of today.

Once you do that, quit your IDE and restart. I had the same issue and thought that upgrading wasn't working. Then I read in the Github issue that you need to restart the IDE. Everything worked after that fine

Comment: Thank you sir! I was reading the same issue, but couldn't get things to work until your comment pointed me to upgrading Typescript itself rather than the eslint package.