# Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined / Line 0: Parsing error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, eslint, create-react-app

For a simple [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev)
project, I run `npm install`.
Then `npm start` opens the default web browser<sup>1</sup>.
Pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> displays two error messages in the console.

[image: Running 'npm start' gives two errors in the browser.]

The error messages are:

- `Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined`, and
- `Line 0:  Parsing error: ImportDeclaration should appear when the mode is ES6 and in the module context`.

***What should I do to rectify these errors?***

---

I have seen these errors elsewhere, sometimes referring to
*version* issues of the packages in `package.json`.
See the reference list below.
I believe references 3-6 may be related to the issues here.

The `.eslintrc.json` and `package.json` files are provided below.
But since they will hardly be sufficient to reproduce the error,
here is a link to
[a zip file containing all the necessary project files](http://user.it.uu.se/%7Ehesc0353/Q71335760.zip).
<sup>2</sup>

`.eslintrc.json` :

```json
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "no-unused-vars": [
      "warn",
      {
        "argsIgnorePattern": "^_",
        "varsIgnorePattern": "^_"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

`package.json` :

```json
{
  "name": "Uncaught ReferenceError",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.2"
  }
}
```

#### References

- [Create React App (CRA)](https://create-react-app.dev)
- [Zip file containing the needed project files](http://user.it.uu.se/%7Ehesc0353/Q71335760.zip)
- [React Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70368760)
- [process is not defined on hot reload](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70357360)
- [Line 0: Parsing error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62079477)
- [React Typescript: Line 0: Parsing error: Cannot read property
  'name' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60729199)

---

<sup>1</sup>
In my case Google Chrome Version 98.0.4758.102, 64-bit.
Running on Windows 10.

<sup>2</sup>
Install the project (locally) by running `npm install` – this may
take about 5-9 minutes.
Then run `npm start` to open the project in the default web browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ***What should I do to rectify these errors?***

#### Answer: update all `npm` packages to their latest versions

Try updating all `npm` packages to their latest versions.
The purpose is to decrease the risk of getting version conflicts.

##### 1. Globally install `npm-check-updates`

In the command line, run :
<sup>1</sup>

```
npm install --global npm-check-updates
```

##### 2. Check for the latest versions

Preview what packages `npm-check-updates` would upgrade :
<sup>2</sup>

```
npm-check-updates
```

If that list looks OK, go ahead and update the packages to their
latest versions in your `package.json` :

```
npm-check-updates --upgrade
```

Here is the terminal response in Windows 10:

[image: Upgrading package.json]

##### 3. Install the latest versions

In the command line, run:
<sup>3</sup>

```
npm install
```

##### 4. Check for errors in the browser and/or in the terminal

In the command line, run:

```
npm start
```

The browser now displays no less than five errors.

[image: Five errors in the web browser]

The terminal confirms the five errors.

[image: Five errors in the terminal]

<sup>^ click to enlarge</sup>

Wow. This looks really, ***really*** bad, doesn't it?

Nope. *Fear not!* – All you need to do now is close the server
(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and run `npm start` once more.
– If you *still* see the errors, do it one more time – close the server
and run `npm start` again.
If that doesn't help either, try waiting about 3-7 minutes before you
try `npm start` again.

When I tried this, I no longer had any errors in the browser.

[image: NO errors in the web browser!]

And the terminal reported *Compiled successfully!*

[image: The terminal says: 'Compiled successfully!']

*Yay!*

#### Reference

- [`npm-check-updates` – documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates)

---

<sup>1</sup>
I am on Windows 10, but I expect all the commands provided here to
work just as fine on Linux and macOS.

<sup>2</sup>
To get a list of options, run `npm-check-updates --help`.

<sup>3</sup>
Expect the `npm install` command to take about 3-8 minutes
to complete.
But if you run it again, it should complete within 10-15 seconds.

Comment: this "solution" is basically like when you misspelled a word you just typed so you're throwing the computer out the window and going to the store to buy the newest that just came out yesterday, thinking it fixed your error.

basically you didn't fix the bug, but you did update ALL OF YOUR DEPENDENCIES, LIBRARIES AND MODULES and on the way your bug in a roundabout kinda way you avoided to have to do with the error.
in a personal home project it might work, but in literally anything else this is not a solution of any kind, and will not work because you'll have to refractor the entire project

Comment: Mass updating everything doesn't break your entire codebase? Wow. I wish we used perfect libraries.